# Can I search for questions whose bodies start with a certain word or phrase?

Tags: support

I have read "[How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)", but I do not see any operators that do what I am trying to do. I see that you can use `body:"phrase here"` to search only in the body, but I was hoping there was some modifier I could use to pin the `"phrase here"` to the beginning of the post. Is this possible?

This is probably not very important; I just thought I had started to notice a trend with questions beginning with a certain word and was curious if I could look at a bunch of different examples of them to verify my theory.

Comment: With Data Explorer only; you may want to use [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126190/unanswered-questions-beginning-with-a-keyword) as a starter.

Comment: Is your magic word "hi"? It seems the filter is malfunctioning (still or again).

Comment: @RadLexus Actually it was "so".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already given the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/126190/unanswered-questions-beginning-with-a-keyword) by [sandwich](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3717023/sandwich) which the best you can get.

If you need to work on almost live data you can use the search options offered in the Stack API on the [`/search/advanced`][1] endpoint. Using those result with a bit of JavaScript can render the results you're looking for.

The below Stack Snippet does exactly that

```js
// hook up button
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function(ce) {
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt').value,
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
      url = ["https://api.stackexchange.com",
             "2.2",
             "search"
             ,"advanced"], 
      query = {
        fromdate: 1462060800,
        order: "desc",
        "sort": "activity",
        "accepted": "False",
        closed: "False",
        body: txt,
        site: "stackoverflow",
        filter: "!)QmBOW*xCRMFqM9X_qP4D0Xt"
        },
      qps = [], 
      qp;
  xhr.addEventListener(
    "load", 
    function(e) {
      var i, 
         q = document.getElementById('q'),
          items = JSON.parse(xhr.response).items, 
          search = txt.toLowerCase(),
          link,
          li;
      // loop over the results to further select matches
      for(i = 0; i<items.length; i++) {
        // <p> is 3 chars, indexOf is zero based
        // fancy regex later ....
        if (items[i].body.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) == 3) { 
          link=document.createElement('a');
          link.href = items[i].link;
          link.textContent = items[i].title;
          li = document.createElement('li');
          li.appendChild(link);
          q.appendChild(li);                             
        }
      }
    });
  for(qp in query){
    qps.push(qp + "=" + query[qp]);
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url.join('/') + "?" + qps.join('&') ); 
  xhr.send();
  
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="txt">Text at start of body:&nbsp;</label>
  <input id="txt"  />
  <button id="go">Search</button>
</div>
<ul id="q">
  
</ul>
```

[1]: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#fromdate=2016-05-01&order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=False&body=Hello&closed=False&filter=!)QmBOW*xCRMFqM9X_qP4D0Xt&site=stackoverflow&run=true